# Running home website through IIS on server itself OR via virtual machine

Tags: php, web, hosting

I have a home server and currently have some code on a webhost for a database that only I use.

I would like to bring the code (PHP) onto my home server to save on cost (as only I use the site its money wasted)

I was going to follow this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N5rxy5Md2ZU and do it through IIS but i have also read about doing it via hyper v.

What would people suggest doing in here?

Comment: HyperV is nice if your machine has the resources for it. If you use HyperV, you can dedicate it to the database, so, you can make image backups that are smaller in size and move it to another machine with ease if you need to rather than have it on your core machine with all your personal info. Plus, it can have it's own network settings aside from your core machines, which can be beneficial when opening ports, etc on your network so your personal stuff is never compromised. Im sure there are way more things than this, but this is just some quick things that come to mind.

Comment: brilliant ... i suppose its more secure